# return the top_k items of each row for sparse tensor

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

For the dense tensor, we can use tf.nn.topk to find values and indices of the k largest entries for the last dimension.

For the sparse tensor, I would like to efficiently get the top n items of each row, without converting the sparse tensor to dense.

Answer (score 1):

This was kind of tricky but here is something that works (assumes 2D sparse tensor, although I think should work the same for more outer dimensions). The idea is to first sort the whole sparse tensor (without making it dense) and then slice the first columns. To do that, I needed something like [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html), which as far as I know is not provided in TensorFlow as such - however, [`tf.sparse.reorder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/reorder) actually does something like a lexsort, so I made another intermediate sparse tensor to take advantage of that.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
# Input data
k = 3
r = np.random.randint(10, size=(6, 8))
r[np.random.rand(*r.shape) < .5] = 0
sp = tf.sparse.from_dense(r)
print(tf.sparse.to_dense(sp).numpy())
# [[0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0]
#  [2 4 0 6 8 0 0 6]
#  [7 0 0 1 5 9 8 9]
#  [4 0 0 3 0 0 0 3]
#  [8 1 0 3 3 7 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 0 7 0 0 7]]

# List of value indices
n = tf.size(sp.values, out_type=sp.indices.dtype)
r = tf.range(n)
# Sort values
s = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.argsort(sp.values, direction='DESCENDING'), sp.indices.dtype)
# Find destination index of each sorted value
si = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(s, 1), r, [n])
# Abuse sparse tensor functionality to do lexsort with column and destination index
sp2 = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=tf.stack([sp.indices[:, 0], si], axis=1),
                             values=r,
                             dense_shape=[sp.dense_shape[0], n])
sp2 = tf.sparse.reorder(sp2)
# Build top-k result
row = sp.indices[:, 0]
# Make column indices
d = tf.dtypes.cast(row[1:] - row[:-1] > 0, r.dtype)
m = tf.pad(r[1:] * d, [[1, 0]])
col = r - tf.scan(tf.math.maximum, m)
# Get only up to k elements per row
m = col < k
row_m = tf.boolean_mask(row, m)
col_m = tf.boolean_mask(col, m)
idx_m = tf.boolean_mask(sp2.values, m)
# Make result
scatter_idx = tf.stack([row_m, col_m], axis=-1)
scatter_shape = [sp.dense_shape[0], k]
# Use -1 for rows with less than k values
# (0 is ambiguous)
values = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(-tf.ones(scatter_shape, sp.values.dtype),
                                     scatter_idx, tf.gather(sp.values, idx_m))
indices = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(-tf.ones(scatter_shape, sp.indices.dtype),
                                      scatter_idx, tf.gather(sp.indices[:, 1], idx_m))
print(values.numpy())
# [[ 3 -1 -1]
#  [ 8  6  6]
#  [ 9  9  8]
#  [ 4  3  3]
#  [ 8  7  3]
#  [ 7  7 -1]]
print(indices.numpy())
# [[ 6 -1 -1]
#  [ 4  3  7]
#  [ 5  7  6]
#  [ 0  3  7]
#  [ 0  5  3]
#  [ 4  7 -1]]
```

---

EDIT: Here is an alternative possibility, which may work well if your tensor is very sparse in all rows. The idea is to "condense" all the sparse tensor values into the first columns (like the previous snippet already did for `sp3`) and then make that into a dense tensor and apply top-k as usual. The caveat is that the indices would be referred to the condensed tensor, so you have to take yet another step if you want to get the right indices with respect to initial sparse tensor.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
# Input data
k = 3
r = np.random.randint(10, size=(6, 8))
r[np.random.rand(*r.shape) < .8] = 0
sp = tf.sparse.from_dense(r)
print(tf.sparse.to_dense(sp).numpy())
# [[0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0]
#  [0 4 0 6 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 5 0 0 9]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [8 0 0 0 0 7 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0]]

# Build "condensed" sparse tensor
n = tf.size(sp.values, out_type=sp.indices.dtype)
r = tf.range(n)
# Make indices
row = sp.indices[:, 0]
d = tf.dtypes.cast(row[1:] - row[:-1] > 0, r.dtype)
m = tf.pad(r[1:] * d, [[1, 0]])
col = r - tf.scan(tf.math.maximum, m)
# At least as many columns as k
ncols = tf.maximum(tf.math.reduce_max(col) + 1, k)
sp2 = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=tf.stack([row, col], axis=1),
                             values=sp.values,
                             dense_shape=[sp.dense_shape[0], ncols])
# Get in dense form
condensed = tf.sparse.to_dense(sp2)
# Top-k (indices do not correspond to initial sparse matrix)
values, indices = tf.math.top_k(condensed, k)
print(values.numpy())
# [[3 0 0]
#  [6 4 0]
#  [9 5 0]
#  [0 0 0]
#  [8 7 0]
#  [7 0 0]]

# Now get the right indices
sp3 = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=tf.stack([row, col], axis=1),
                             values=sp.indices[:, 1],
                             dense_shape=[sp.dense_shape[0], ncols])
condensed_idx = tf.sparse.to_dense(sp3)
actual_indices = tf.gather_nd(condensed_idx, tf.expand_dims(indices, axis=-1),
                              batch_dims=1)
print(actual_indices.numpy())
# [[6 0 0]
#  [3 1 0]
#  [7 4 0]
#  [0 0 0]
#  [0 5 0]
#  [4 0 0]]
```

Not sure whether this would be faster or not though.

Comment: Code is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. It works, and we can use the tf.where(col < k) and tf.gather_nd to get the results instead of create sp3.  Although it saves space, the training of the model is much slower. Is there any way to solve it？

Comment: @Ryvius Doesn't really surprise me... I don't know how to speed it up, I added a second possibility though, making a "condensed" version of the sparse tensor which might be small enough to work with it as a dense tensor, depending on your case...

Comment: Thanks again. The "condense" version has a certain acceleration effect, but there is still a big gap compared with directly converting to dense tensor.

Comment: @Ryvius Yes, I don't think you will be able to do it with a sparse tensor nearly as fast as with a dense tensor... I edited the first solution, simplifying it a bit, which may make it slightly faster, but probably not a whole lot.